# Help debugging Sendmail/Mailman configuration issue

Tags: linux, email, sendmail, alias, mailman

I'm trying to configure a server with Sendmail and Mailman.  I've been getting "Broken pipe" errors for a while, and have slowly been debugging.  I fixed some permission issues, and changed the user that Mailman expects to be called from, among other things.  Finally, I'd gone through everything I could think of, so I added a new test to see if it's the Mailman script or Sendmail that's causing the problem.  Here's the error I'm getting now (stripped of timestamps and identifying information):

```
<-- MAIL FROM:me@mydomain.com
Authentication-Warning: xxxxx.org: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.net [xx.xx.xxx.xxx] didn't use HELO protocol
--- 250 2.1.0 me@mydomain.com... Sender ok
<-- RCPT TO: cmtest@xxxxx.org
--- 250 2.1.5 cmtest@xxxxx.org... Recipient ok
<-- DATA
--- 354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
from=me@mydomain.com, size=20, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201007202254.o6KMg2xZ025804@xxxxx.org>, proto=SMTP, relay=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.net [xx.xx.xxx.xxx]
--- 250 2.0.0 o6KMg2xZ025804 Message accepted for delivery
 alias cmtest@xxxxx.org => "|/bin/echo foo"
 SYSERR(root): putbody: write error: Broken pipe
   0: fl=0x0, mode=20660: CHR: dev=0/15, ino=776, nlink=1, u/gid=0/0, size=0
   1: fl=0x1, mode=20660: CHR: dev=0/15, ino=776, nlink=1, u/gid=0/0, size=0
   2: fl=0x1, mode=20660: CHR: dev=0/15, ino=776, nlink=1, u/gid=0/0, size=0
   3: fl=0x2, mode=140777: SOCK localhost->[[UNIX: /dev/log]]
   5: fl=0x0, mode=100600: dev=8/3, ino=486765, nlink=1, u/gid=0/51, size=5
   6: fl=0x8000, mode=100640: dev=8/3, ino=65501, nlink=1, u/gid=0/0, size=12288
   7: fl=0x8000, mode=100640: dev=8/3, ino=65501, nlink=1, u/gid=0/0, size=12288
   8: fl=0x8000, mode=100640: dev=8/3, ino=65510, nlink=1, u/gid=0/0, size=12288
   9: fl=0x8000, mode=100640: dev=8/3, ino=65510, nlink=1, u/gid=0/0, size=12288
  10: fl=0x8000, mode=100640: dev=8/3, ino=64814, nlink=1, u/gid=0/51, size=12288
  11: fl=0x8000, mode=100640: dev=8/3, ino=64814, nlink=1, u/gid=0/51, size=12288
  12: fl=0x1, mode=100600: dev=8/3, ino=486767, nlink=1, u/gid=0/51, size=754
  13: fl=0x1, mode=10600: FIFO: dev=0/5, ino=7649785, nlink=1, u/gid=0/51, size=0
  14: fl=0x0, mode=10600: FIFO: dev=0/5, ino=7649786, nlink=1, u/gid=0/51, size=0
 MCI@0x0: NULL
 MCI@0x0: NULL
 to="|/bin/echo foo", ctladdr=cmtest@xxxxx.org (8/0), delay=00:00:08, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=prog, pri=30476, dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
 o6KMsnxX025948: DSN: Service unavailable
 done; delay=00:00:08, ntries=1
```

The alias in `/etc/aliases` is:

```
 cmtest: "|/bin/echo foo"
```

As you can see, even when trying to pipe to `/bin/echo` I still get the same error.  But I can't for the life of me figure out what else to check.  Normal aliases work fine.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, I decided to just go ahead and switch to Postfix, which will probably be better in the end.  It's still not 100%, but at least I'm making progress now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is sendmail restricted shell, smrsh which only allows sendmail to execute programs that are in the /etc/smrsh directory